# The center (x and y axis) of my 2D cartesian graph color not changing accordingly in Plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have this code that makes a 2D cartesian graph and I came across a strange problem. While the quadrant shapes color is changing according to the code, the ones under #AXIS are not changing to black and remaining white, even though im using the same fig.add_shape function, and specifying a black color. It still shows white.

```
# PLOTLY
axis_range = [-9, 9]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_xaxes(range=axis_range, title='', tickmode='linear', showticklabels=False, side='top', gridcolor="rgb(224,224,224)", showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(range=axis_range, title='', tickmode='linear', showticklabels=False, side='right', gridcolor="rgb(224,224,224)", showgrid=False)

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', height=800, width=800, margin=dict(l=125, r=125, t=125, b=125))
fig.update_layout(autosize=True)

# AXIS
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=-9, y0=0, x1=9, y1=0, fillcolor="#000000", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=0, y0=-9, x1=0, y1=9, fillcolor="#000000", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)

# Adding color to quadrant
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=-9, y0=-9, x1=0, y1=0, fillcolor="#C8E4BC", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=0, y0=-9, x1=9, y1=0, fillcolor="#F5F5A7", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=-9, y0=0, x1=0, y1=9, fillcolor="#F9BABA", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)
fig.add_shape(type="rect", x0=0, y0=0, x1=9, y1=9, fillcolor="#92D9F8", opacity=1, layer="below", line_width=0,)
```

What could be the issue here? here is an screenshot:
[image: graph]

Comment: The solution is to set the layer parameter to "above" instead of "below" for the #AXIS shapes.

Comment: That does not explain why it shows white, i have "below" for all the rest of shapes and they show their corresponding colors instead of white.

Also my issue is, when i set them to "above", they become above the scatter points as well. which i do not want.

Comment: To get around this, you can try setting the opacity to 0 instead of 1. This will make the shape invisible but still have the same effect as having a black fill color. This should also allow the scatter points to be on top of the shapes.

Comment: But that would leave the area white, which I'm trying to set to black.

Basically, I want the "axis" to be black and still be able to have scatter points appear above them.

Comment: In order to achieve this, you can specify a background color for the whole figure by using the plot_bgcolor parameter in the update_layout() function. This will set the background color for the entire figure, including the axis shapes. Now the axis shapes can remain black and the scatter points will appear above them.

Comment: Strangely enough, I actually did try that and added plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)' to fig.update_layout, and the color remained white on the axis lines.

Comment: I mean I could always just use an image to achieve what I want, but it is very strange that I cannot find a solution to that particular thing.